# how to see four buttons in the first row and a list of images in second row?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am writing this code, but I can´t see the buttons, only the images. I am usiang xamaring forms in visual studio for a mobile app.I need to see both elements, the buttons in the first row and de images in the second row

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView
            Padding="{ StaticResource MainWrapperPadding }">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="1" BackgroundColor="#FFE53C25"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="2" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="3" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="4" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

<artina:GridOptionsView
                    x:Name="promotionsList"
                    Margin="0"
                    ColumnSpacing="0" 
                    RowSpacing="0" 
                    Padding="2" 
                    ColumnCount="{
                        artina:OnOrientationInt 
                            PortraitPhone=2,
                            LandscapePhone=3,

                            PortraitTablet=3,
                            LandscapeTablet=4,

                            PortraitDesktop=4,
                            LandscapeDesktop=4
                    }"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:PromotionItemTemplate HeightRequest="296" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                </artina:GridOptionsView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>-->
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You only have things on the first row of the grid. Maybe put something on other rows so they don’t overlap?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if I write in the artina gridoptionsview, gris.row=1 for example.I only see one buttons and the images whit the artina options size. Not the four buttons and the images

Answer (score 0):

Here i am going to make more easy of your task adding more fields

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="0" >
  <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1" />
      <RowDefinition Height="2" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Blue" >


           <Button  Text="1" BackgroundColor="#FFE53C25"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button  Text="2" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button  Text="3" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button  Text="4" BackgroundColor="#98A4AE"
                FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />




    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red" >


               <artina:GridOptionsView
                    x:Name="promotionsList"
                    Margin="0"
                    ColumnSpacing="0" 
                    RowSpacing="0" 
                    Padding="2" 
                    ColumnCount="{
                        artina:OnOrientationInt 
                            PortraitPhone=2,
                            LandscapePhone=3,

                            PortraitTablet=3,
                            LandscapeTablet=4,

                            PortraitDesktop=4,
                            LandscapeDesktop=4
                    }"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:PromotionItemTemplate HeightRequest="296" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </artina:GridOptionsView.ItemTemplate>
                </artina:GridOptionsView>


    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

stack layout with grid rows